# Acceleration and gravitation are locally equivalent ? I find not

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, time-dilation, equivalence-principle

In a gravitational field, the above and below clocks do not run at the same rate.
The acceleration equivalent means that the simultaneity changes. During acceleration there would be a gravitational time dilation and two accelerated clocks should not run at the same rate.

But it is not what we see. We see that the clocks do run at the same rate since they have to be reset by hand.

Let me repeat:
According to the equivalence principle, the accelerated clocks should be out of sync when viewed from the stationary frame of reference, which is not the case. Their world line will be identical. Then these clocks do not get out of sync.

In the gravitational field the clocks do not move at the same rate, so the observed redshift is of temporal origin.

In acceleration, the clocks move at the same rate because undergo the same time dilation. The Einstein synchronised clocks will highlight the redshift due to the change in the speed of light relative to them during acceleration because they continue to beat at the same rate unlike the gravitational case. After acceleration it will be necessary to resynchronise them by hand, whereas in the gravitational case it is not necessary to resynchronise them, they do it by themselves.
So I find acceleration and gravitation are not equivalent.

Is there any mistake ?

**Edit** - The mistake was here :
"whereas in the gravitational case it is not necessary to resynchronise them, they do it by themselves"

Of course, in a gravitational field it is necessary to resynchronise them too.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any mistake ?

Yes. The primary mistake that you are making is misstating and misapplying the equivalence principle.

The equivalence principle does not simply claim that “acceleration is equivalent to gravitation”. The equivalence principle specifically states that:

The outcome of any local experiment in a freely falling laboratory is independent of the velocity of the laboratory and its location in spacetime.

From this statement you can *derive* the fact that the gravitational force is locally equivalent to a fictitious force in an accelerated reference frame. So the equivalence is between the local gravitational field and an accelerated *reference frame*, not simply “acceleration” in general.

In the case of your assertions, it is not correct that

> We see that the clocks do run at the same rate since they have to be reset by hand.

Nor is it correct that

> After acceleration it will be necessary to resynchronise them by hand, whereas in the gravitational case it is not necessary to resynchronise them, they do it by themselves.

To the best and most accurate of all of our observations the equivalence principle holds when it is correctly applied. Misunderstanding or misapplying the principle in no way invalidates it.

Comment: Sorry, but if you don't know that clocks have to be resynchronised by hand after an acceleration, then you are missing something. The clocks remain synchronized in the reference frame of the stationary observer, as their world lines are the same length in it, but they are desynchronized in the reference frame of the clocks. The clocks must be re-synchronised to restore their simultaneity. This is not the case in a gravitational field.

Comment: @externo that is just incorrect. Clocks at rest wrt each other in a local gravitational field become desynchronized  just as do clocks at rest in an accelerated frame in flat spacetime.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was wrong about the gravity situation. I don't know why I made that mistake.